# ACF repeater field only show one row

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, repeater

I've got a problem with some code below
I use wordpress and the plugin ACF PRO. 
I query some posts and in this posts their is a repeater field, but it seems that it shows only the first row of the repeater field 'evenement'.
I don't know if it's very clear ?

Somebody can help me.

Thanks

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query(
array( 
'category__not_in' => array(520),
'category__and' => array(2905,1582),
'post_status' => array( 'draft'),
'post_type' => 'spectacles',
'lang' => 'fr',
'showposts' => -1,
'meta_key' => 'date_debut',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC')
);?> 

<?php if($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <div id="bloc-picto">
        <div class="item-picto">
            <img src="<?php $picto = get_field('picto');if( !empty($picto) ): ?><?php echo $picto['url']; ?><?php else: ?><?php $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(); $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'icon', true); echo $image_url[0];  ?><?php endif; ?>" width="40px" height="40px">
        </div>
        <div class="legend-picto">
        <b><?php the_title(); ?></b>
            <?php if( get_field('compagnie') ): ?>
            <?php the_field('compagnie'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <br/>
            <?php if( get_field('acces_star') ): ?>
            <div style="font-size:10px"><?php the_field('acces_star'); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if( have_rows('evenement') ): while ( have_rows('evenement') ) : the_row(); ?>
            <?php $post_object = get_sub_field('lieu_evenement');if( $post_object ):
            $post = $post_object; setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                <i><?php the_title(); ?></i>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What type of field is the subfield "lieu_evenement"? The problem might be coming from resetting the postdata, and depending on your field type for that subfield, that might need to be reworked. The actual repeater code looks right, so I'd think it's coming from setting up and resetting postdata that may not need to be done.

Comment: The subfield "lieu_evenement" is a post object ! You think it's because of that ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with the have_rows() loop only returning the first layout when essentially nesting one query within another.

My solution was to redefine the $post variable after each layout. For example:

```
$post = 123;

setup_postdata( $post );

if ( have_rows( 'components' ) ) {
   while ( have_rows( 'components' ) ) {
      the_row();
      $course_tmpl_name = str_replace( '_', '-', get_row_layout() );
      // include your layout php here
      $post = 123; // redefine $post
   }
}   

wp_reset_postdata();
```